# Keeping SASS Code DRY using Media Queries

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

I have two media queries. One is for phones while the other is for tablets. They both call for the same exact styling. In this case what would be the best approach for keeping this code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

```
$mobile-portrait: "only screen and (max-width: 680px)";
$tablet-portrait: "only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait)";

div {
    background: gray; margin: 0 auto; height: 50px; width: 50px;

    @media #{$mobile-portrait} {
        height: 100px; width: 100px;
    }

   @media #{$tablet-portrait} {
       height: 100px; width: 100px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's any good way to do this, but you could always just create multiple selectors. (I don't know if that's the best practice, but that's what I would do.)

```
@media #{$mobile-portrait},
@media #{$tablet-portrait} {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT:** The following is also valid.

```
@media #{$mobile-portrait}, @media #{$tablet-portrait} {
   height: 100px; width: 100px;
}
```

For aesthetic I prefer putting the selectors on multiple lines. When there are longer selectors, the line break helps differentiate between them.

I also prefer the styles on multiple lines. If you have more than about three or four in a selector, it can get confusing.

**EDIT 2:** The comma actually acts like a logical `or` when inside of a media query.

Per this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

> #### comma-separated lists
>
> Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator `or` when used in media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not affect the others. This means the comma-separated media queries can target different media features, types, and states.

Which means that the second `@media` is not necessary:

```
@media #{$mobile-portrait}, #{$tablet-portrait} {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick but my only question is why not display both the media queries inline as you did previously? This has been a question I've always wondered when viewing certain media queries written by others.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Please see my edit. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: After moving the code to another computer I'm getting this error when using the code above: Invalid CSS after "...ile-portrait}, ": expected media query (e.g. print, screen, print and screen), was "@media #{$table...")

Comment: The first example does not compile.

Comment: The second example doesn't compile either.

Comment: Oh wow... That's odd. I wonder if it's because of multiple `@media` queries... What errors are you getting?

Comment: Check the third comment

Comment: Are `$mobile-portrait` and `$tablet-portrait` defined on your other computer?

Comment: Yeah, I actually copied and pasted the exact stylesheet.

Comment: As a matter of fact it doesn't work on either computer. Those changes must've not compiled last night.

Comment: Does it work if you manually enter the entire query? (`@media only screen and...`.)

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for the help! And in addition to the fix I learned something along the way.

Comment: Awesome! I learned something too! I'll remember this next time I need to do multiple media queries.